# Program that outputs a pattern that looks like the union jack given the size

Tags: java, ascii

so my program is supposed to output a pattern like the union jack for ex:

```
3 =      ,     7 = 

0X0            0  X  0
XXX             0 X 0 
0X0              0X0
               XXXXXXX
                 0X0
                0 X 0
               0  X  0
```

here is my code so far...
can someone find what is wrong? i dont really know whats wrong, it outputs a pattern thats similar but the spaces are all wrong

```
import java.util.*;
public class uj {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input;
        int counter2=1;
        int counter1=1;

        do{
            System.out.println("Enter size(must be odd): ");
            input = sc.nextInt();
        }while(input/2==0);

        int half = (input/2)+1;
        while(counter1<=input+1){
            while(counter2<=input+1){
                if(counter2==counter1 || counter2==(input-counter1)){
                    System.out.print("0");
                }else if(counter2==half && counter1!=half){
                    System.out.print("x");
                }else if(counter1==half){
                    System.out.print("x");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(" ");

                }
                counter2++;
            }
            System.out.println("");
            counter1++;

            counter2=0; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: input/2==0 should be input%2==0

Comment: Can you also add the output that you actually get for those numbers? And please format it properly, either by using `<pre>` tags or by indenting it as code using the `{}` button.

Comment: Use for loops for counting - avoid while.

Comment: iObserve the character in the center: it's an `X`, so printing an `X` must have preference over printing an `0`.

Comment: `counter2=0;` All other initializations of counters use `=1` - a sign that something is amiss. Change this to 1.

Comment: Finally: the upper limit should be `input`, not `input+1`. This is the last thing you'd need to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to print a NxN square of characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int input;
  do {
    System.out.println("Enter size(must be odd): ");
    input = sc.nextInt();
  } while(input%2 == 0);

  int half = input/2 + 1;
  for( int iRow = 1; iRow <= input; ++iRow ){
    for( int iCol = 1; iCol <= input; ++iCol ){
      // Highest precedence: middle row, middle column
      if( iRow == half || iCol == half ){
        System.out.print( 'X' );
      } else
      // next, the diagonals
      if( iRow == iCol || input - iCol + 1 == iRow ){
        System.out.print( '0' );
      } else {
        // the rest is white space
        System.out.print( ' ' );
      }
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, im not really that good at these kind of things and this helps a lot for me to improve my logic in making these kind programs